# C++ trying to call an object method inside another object

Tags: c++

I am trying to make my client which is the A class to call the method inside the serverstub class which is B.

The client class should take the host address as input 
I cannot make objB global variable becuse it need the input to be created.
so now when I try to compile it just say it was not declared inside the scope.

```
class A {
   public:
      A(string host){
        B objB(host);
      }
      void amethod(int) {
         objB.bmethod(); // here 
      }
};

class B {
   public:
      B(string host)
      void bmethod(void) {}
};

main(int argc, char*argv[]) {
  string host;

  if(argc>1){
    host = string(argv[1]);
  } else{
    host = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
  }

  A objA(host);
}
```

Comment: Make `objB` member variable.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make objB a member variable of class A, then you can initialize it when objA is consturcted, as follows

```
class A
{
private:
   B objB;
public:
   A(string host);
};

A::A(string host): objB(host) {}
```

Then, you can call any method in ObjB later from ObjA.